# Is it correct way of thinking in my conception?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, javascript-objects

I try to write an advanced application in Node.js but I'm not sure if my way of thinking in my code is correct. First of all I would like to say something about my application. My application will be showing results on-line without refreshing page. First of all, I have to create an array with teams which will be playing. Assume that we have 2 matches like that:

```
var Schedule = [ {id:199, team1:{name:"Detroit",id:24319}, team2: {name: "San Antonio", id:32543}, date: "20.11.2015 12:00"},
                 {id: 200, team1: {name: "Boston", id: 23113}, team2: {name: "Los Angeles", id:25966}, date: "19.12.2015 10:00"} ];
```

Secondly, when the match is going to start, I have to start match with create an object. Properties of this match I put into array: "Matches".

```
var Matches = [];
Schedule.forEach(function(a,b){ 
        Schedule.splice(a,1); 
        new Match(a.team1,a.team2,a.id);
        var matchProperties = {"id": a.id, "team1": a.team1 , "team2":a.team2, "date": a.date, "result1":0, "result2":0, "minute":0 };
        Matches.push(matchProperties);
```

My factory of of the Matches is like that:

```
function Match(team1,team2,id) {
    this.team1.name = team1;
    this.team2.name = team2;
    this.id = id;
    this.initialize();
};

Match.prototype =  {
    id: 0,
    minute: 0,
    team1: {"name": ""},
    team2: {"name": ""},
    result1: 0,
    result2: 0,
    events: [],

    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;

        setInterval(function(){
            that.minute++;

        Matches.forEach(function(a,b,theArray) {

            if(a.id == that.id) {
                theArray[b].minute = that.minute;
            if(that.minute == 5)
                that.score(theArray[b].team1,3);
            if(that.minute == 10)
                that.score(theArray[b].team1,2);
            if(that.minute == 20)
                that.score(theArray[b].team1,3);
            if(that.minute > 90)
                return;
                }
        });

        },1000);

    },
    score: function(team,points) {
        var that = this;
        Matches.forEach(function(a,b,theArray) {

            if(a.id == that.id) {

                if(team.name == theArray[b].team1){
                    theArray[b].result1 = theArray[b].result1 + points;

                }
                if(team.name == theArray[b].team2)
                    theArray[b].result2 = theArray[b].result2 + points;
                var message = that.getAction('score',team,points);

                that.events.push(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and now, I send my data to result page:

```
setInterval(function() {
    io.sockets.emit('results', Matches);
},1000);
```

and now, I have a problem with my code because every method needs forEach function and in my opinion it's wrong way to get number of match and after that make changes in this match. Every execution of this command: new Match(a.team1,a.team2,a.id); should be seperate object and for example method score should change only one Match as reference in array.

and I have question, is it correct way? Maybe do you have any ideas to makes better of my code? Every reply will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for trying to understand advanced javascript concepts, wanting use them properly, and asking the community for feedback. This question may need to be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com, however.

Comment: Yes, this question is also pretty much opinionated. I'm actually quite astonished to see this question not being closed already. I had way less opinionated questions being closed within 15 minutes... and you even got upvotes for this. :P